# FCM Notification through Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, notifications, alarmmanager

I am making an android application which will send a FCM notification to device first it will check nearby places in my database. I am new to android I want to send Api to server after 5 minutes to check nearby places if any exist then send FCM notification on that device. I studied about Alarm Manager but I am confused how can I make a background thread to send api after 5 minutes even app is active or not. Please guide me Thanks

Comment: I think in order for the community to engage with your question a) check to see if there are potential tutorials on the wider internet to help you with smaller parts of your question and b) outline here what you've already tried and where exactly you need help with your attempt

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell,

1. Create an `IntentService` that will do the work. This can be tested independent of alarms of course. You can use `adb shell am startservice ...` to test.
2. In your code that receives the cloud message, create an `Intent` that starts your service from (1).
3. Wrap the intent from (2) in a `PendingIntent`.
4. Use `AlarmManager.set()` to schedule the `PendingIntent` from (3) to fire when you want.

Comment: Using Android Studio Could You please give me a demo or example thanks'

Comment: I think I provided all of the search terms to get you started. I'm not going to write a sample app for you. Good luck.